# Bad request error in ajax while sending huge data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to send nearly 1 to 100000 mobile numbers through ajax .When i can able to send nealry 400 to 500 numbers when i am sending more than 500 numbers i am getting Bad Request error.I tried with `POST` method also.

Is there any possibility send huge data through AJAX.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: There is maybe a limit to increase on server side, others will tell you more. You could also do multiple requests.

Answer (score 0):

Using POST submission you shouldn't have problem. It's maybe your webserver that causes trouble? Maybe you should increase the max post length or something like that.

Comment: i am using Tomcat.How i can increase?

Comment: If you look at the documentation: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html you will see that there is a maxPostSize value. By default it is 2Mo so it's quite low.

Comment: If i did that also i am having the same problem

Comment: Try increasing maxParameterCount and maxSavePostSize too

Answer (score 0):

No way a mere 500 mobile numbers should hit any sort of limits. Lets say this amounts to 10Kb. That is not huge in any sense.

Bad Request is malformed data simple as that. http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E400.html

You could try sending a single good number repeated 1000 times.